# Unable to insert into Firebase on adding window.location.href

Tags: firebase

I am able to insert data into firebase using the below javascript lines.

```
var myFirebaseRef = new Firebase("<Firebase URL>");
myFirebaseRef.set({
    title: "Hello World!",
    author: "Firebase",
    location: {
        city: "San Francisco",
        state: "California",
        zip: 94103
    }
});
```

But when I add, `window.location.href="Home.html";` at the end, it redirects to Home.html, without inserting into Firebase.
What can be the reason?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you add `window.location.href="Home.html"` after your `myFirebaseRef.set` call, you get redirected before firebase has had a chance to commit the write to the server.
To execute some code after the write has been committed, you can use the completion callback :

```
myFirebaseRef.set(newData, function(error){
    window.location.href="Home.html";
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There might not be enough time to update data in the database as changing the href loads another page. So you can add like this

```
var myFirebaseRef = new Firebase("<Firebase URL>");
myFirebaseRef.set({
    title: "Hello World!",
    author: "Firebase",
    location: {
        city: "San Francisco",
        state: "California",
        zip: 94103
    }
}, (error) => {
      if (error) {
       // The write failed...
      } else {
       // Data saved successfully!
       window.location.href="Home.html";
      }
});
```

Reference [firebase docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write?authuser=3#add_a_completion_callback)